# Реализуйте функцию которая принимает строку и удаляет все пробелы javascript! Помогите с заданием!

Tags: javascript

Реализуйте функцию которая принимает строку и удаляет все пробелы javascript! Помогите с заданием!

Comment: УЧИТЕ УРОКИ до того как надо сдавать задания!!! А в остальном посмотрите функции `replace` и `replaceAll` для работы со строками

Comment: .replace(/\s/g, '');

Answer (score 1):

Сама функция:

```
function removeSpaces(input) {
  return input.split(' ').join('');
}
```

Её вызов:

```
let result = removeSpaces(' Hello  World !');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как забить микроскопом гвоздь :)

Comment: @Zhihar, насколько мне известно, эта реализация быстрее input.replace(/\s/g, '');

Comment: да, беру свои слова обратно - проверил, `split` работает в 1,5 раза быстрее, чем `replaceAll`